# how to detect if command execute failed in shell?

Tags: shell-script, exit-status

I use Java to call a shell script in remote machine.

I want to know if the shell execute failed. But I found that, checking the return code `$?` after the script is finished doesn't work. `$?` only indicate the last command's result code in the script.

So even a command execute failed, but the last command execute success. I can't find it. I want to know how to solve the problem?

Need I check the result code for every command in shell? And if one command execute failed, exit the script?

Comment: have you considered having the remote script create a log file? After execution, you'll be able to return exit value based on scanning the exit log (e.g. 1 for error phrase is log file).

By convention `$?` returns the exit status of the last command executed in a script or in a function. [Exit status](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `set -e` inside the script, or pass `-e` to the interpreter when launching.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
```

or

```
/bin/sh -e /path/to/script.sh
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/set.html:

> -e
>
> When this option is on, if a simple command fails for any of the reasons listed in Consequences of Shell Errors or returns an exit
>   status value >0, and is not part of the compound list following a
>   while, until, or if keyword, and is not a part of an AND or OR list,
>   and is not a pipeline preceded by the ! reserved word, then the shell
>   shall immediately exit.

Comment: It's OK, but I have a `grep` operation in my shell, and the script exit when the `grep` failed. The if statement `if [ echo $line | grep -q "$field" ] ; then` seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the trap.

```
trap 'command' signal
```

Your shell script may like this:

```
trap 'trapHandler $LINENO' ERR
```

to catch the ERR signal. `trapHandler()` can be like this.

```
trapHandler()
{
    retCode=$?
    echo "[LINE:$1] Error:exited with status $retCode"
    exit $retCode
}
```

Comment: @NingLee For your question, just `if echo $line | grep -q "$field"` the check it.